# VS code shortcut to wrap multiple lines of text in same tag?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I have a text file containing 100 lines of words.
Need to wrap them all in li tags to display as bullet points on a website.
How to do so fast in VS code using some shortcut?
If I paste the text in VS code, it takes up 100 lines with one word on each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>
2. Enable Regular Expression
3. Enter `^(.*)$` in Find
4. Enter `<li>$1</li>` in Replace
5. Profit

```
foo
bar
baz asdad
foo bar baz 123
```

Becomes

```
<li>foo</li>
<li>bar</li>
<li>baz asdad</li>
<li>foo bar baz 123</li>
```

Answer (score 4):

- place cursor on line 1 and `Shift+Alt+Click` on line 100
- press `Home` and `Shift+End`
- execute command: **Emmet: wrap with abbreviation**
- enter `li` and `Enter`

Comment: place a cursor manually for 100 lines? no thanks

Comment: @ToveC. use cursor on line 1 and `Shift+Alt+Click` on line 100

Comment: okay that sounds good, let me try. Thanks!

Comment: to execute the command, we should press Ctrl + Shift + P